# How to access this in constructor?

Tags: dart

I want to pass the instance of a class `this` when constructing my class.

```
class A implements B {

   final C _c = ConcreteClass(b: this);
}
```

It looks like this cannot be done because `this` doesn't exist yet. I usually do this in other languages like Java and Kotlin. Any idea how to do this in Dart?

I tried to do it in the constructor but it is the same.

Comment: In short: Declare `late final C _c;` and then initialize it in the constructor's *body*, when `this` is valid: `A() { _c = ConcreteClass(b: this); }`

Comment: Wow you can late final? That is amazing.

Comment: The duplicate answer question does not even mention assigning `this` within a constructor. I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Look again.  It explicitly explains that `this` is available in constructor bodies.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin. You blew my mind with combining `late` and `final`. Super cool.

Comment: I forgot, you also can do just: `late final C _c = ConcreteClass(b: this);`.  Using `late` will make `_c` initialized lazily, after `this` becomes valid.

Comment: @jamesdlin you just made my day! This makes me so happy. Thank you!